# Manually Sorting an Array in Ascending Order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a homework assignment to sort an array in ascending order. Obviously, this is to be done manually without using any kind of `sort()` function.

I figured to do it, I would need two `for` loops: the first one will loop through the existing array and create a temporary value with the value and index of the array. The second loop will compare the temporary values to the existing values and sort them. I keep trying to write the code, but I just can’t seem to get it right. Here is the latest method I came up with:

```
public int[] sortArray (int[] inArray)
{
    //Construct the array we're using here
    int[] newArray = inArray;

    for(int x = 0; x < a.length; x++) //a.length = # of indices in the array
    {
        int tempValue = a[x];
        int tempIndex = x;

        for(int y = 0; y < a.length; y++)
        {
            if(tempValue < a[y])
            {
                newArray[x] = tempValue;
            }
        }
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

I’m pretty sure this is incorrect, but if someone could push me in the right direction it would be very appreciated!

Comment: It might be worth you firstly looking at some pseudo code for different sorting algorithms: http://maven.smith.edu/~thiebaut/java/sort/

Comment: Are you supposed to use a certain sort algorithm?

Comment: Unless you were explicitly asked to think up your sorting algorithm, I recommend finding a simple one and implementing it in your code. And instead of being "pretty sure" that your code is incorrect, just test it and find out.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm must be my own. And by "pretty sure it doesn't work", I mean it doesn't work, but I'm hoping to only have to slightly modify the code to get it working, rather then starting from scratch again.

Comment: You use variable `a` which is nowhere to be seen. Use inArray instead of it. The right way to create a new array is `int[] newArray = new int[inArray.length];`.

Comment: Sorry, I only posted a snippet of code. `a` is the original array I'm sorting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a nearly OK version of the [Selection Sorter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). You need to start your `y` at `x+1`, not at `0`. Otherwise you're re-scanning the sorted portion of the array. You should also note that selection sort is an in-place algorithm; if you are looking to make a *copy* of the array, you should use `Arrays.copy` method, otherwise `int[] newArray = inArray;`
 is creating an alias, not a copy. Finally, the `if` statement in the nested loop should *swap* `a[x]` and `a[y]`, not simply put `tempValue` in:

```
if(newArray[x] < newArray [y]) {
    int tempValue = newArray[y];
    newArray[y] = newArray[x];
    newArray[x] = tempValue;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the swap part?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `Arrays.copy`! I kinda have been overlooking that, but it turns out that was my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to invent your own sorting algorithm, I'd urge you to study what already exists. There's a *ton* of prior art on this.

Take a look at the Wikipedia article: [Sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

[Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is very easy to implement, but has quadratic complexity (the same as your current attempt).

[Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) isn't too hard to implement either, and has better average complexity.

Answer (score 2):

```
int minval = input[0];
int temp=0;


for(int i = 0; i< input.length; i++)
{ 
    for(int j = 0; j< input.length-1; j++)
    {
        if(input[j+1]<input[j])
        {
            temp=input[j+1];
            input[j+1]=input[j];
            input[j]=temp;  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sorting you are trying to achieve is called [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) - the wikipedia entry is pretty good you should read it. Though, it's never really used because there is better alternative - [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) (An example is Timsort in Python which is a hybrid of Merge sort and Insertion sort). These two are the basic algorithms that fits your idea with two loops, hence O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

You should also consider different algorithms for your assignment or, at least, be aware of:

- [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
- [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[] = new int[]{10, 20, 5, 6, 30, 1, 2};
    boolean bool = true;
    int t = 0;
    while (bool) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                int c = arr[i];

                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = c;
                t++;
            }
        }
        if (t == 0) {
            bool = false;
        }
        t = 0;
    }

    for (int y : arr) {
        System.out.println(y);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] number = { 1,2,1,3,5,4 };
    int temp;
     for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < number.length; j++)
            {
                if (number[i] > number[j])
                {
                    temp =  number[i];
                    number[i] = number[j];
                    number[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <number.length; ++i)
            System.out.println(number[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.