# access all array value outside the loop and group them

Tags: java, arrays

How can I access all values or arrays outside the loop? I want to access it outside the loop is because I need to group them according to `availableID`. I have tried to group them inside the loop, the result is not as what i expected..

Expected outcome:

```
Student Name    Project Title   Supervisor Name Examiner Name   Start   End Date
2013438096           Hello              1025          1003        7      7  null
2013339255           Hello              1024          1001        7      7  null

Student Name    Project Title   Supervisor Name Examiner Name   Start   End Date
2013366609        Hello                 1027          1013         2      2 null 
2011679914        Hello                 1015          1014         2      2 null 
2013765397        Hello                 1026          1014         2      2 null
```

However, it turns out to be like this:

```
Student Name    Project Title   Supervisor Name Examiner Name   Start   End Date
2013339255       Hello               1024           1001          7       7 null



Student Name    Project Title   Supervisor Name Examiner Name   Start   End Date
2013438096       Hello              1025           1003           7       7 null



Student Name    Project Title   Supervisor Name Examiner Name   Start   End Date
2013765397         Hello                1026         1014          2    2   null



Student Name    Project Title   Supervisor Name Examiner Name   Start   End Date
2011679914         Hello                1015         1014          2    2   null



Student Name    Project Title   Supervisor Name Examiner Name   Start   End Date
2013366609         Hello                1027          1013         2    2   null
```

I figured i should group them outside the loop, so this is my logic:

```
try{ 
            String studentName = null;
            String projectTitle = null;
            String SVName = null;
            String EXName = null;
            int availID = 0;
            String day = null;
            Time start = null;
            Time end = null;
            Date date = null;

            for (int i=0 ; i<studentID.length ; i++){

               List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i],studentID[i]);

               Object[] array = null;

               if(!list.isEmpty()){

                //declaring the variables
                  studentName = (String) array[7];
                  ....... // all variables
                  date = (Date) array[3];

                }//check list is NOT empty
                else if (list.isEmpty()){

                  list = (List<Object[]>) GenerateScheduleDAO.getOtherFree(examinerID[i], supervisorID[i],studentID[i]);


                   //declaring the variables
                   studentName = (String) array[7];
                   ....... // all variables
                   date = (Date) array[3];                

                }

   }//student loop

             if (availID == 2) {
                     out.println("<br><center><table id=\"t01\"><tr>"
                             + "<th>7Student Name</th>"
                             + "<th>Project Title</th>"
                             + "<th>Supervisor Name</th>"
                             + "<th>Examiner Name</th>"
                             + "<th>Day</th>"
                             + "<th>Start</th>"
                             + "<th>End</th>"
                             + "<th>Date</th>"
                             + "</tr>");
                     out.println("<tr>");
                     out.println("<td>"+ studentName+"</td>");
                     out.println("<td>"+ projectTitle +"</td>");
                     out.println("<td>"+ SVName +"</td>");
                     out.println("<td>"+ EXName +"</td>");
                     out.println("<td>"+ day +"</td>");
                     out.println("<td>"+ start +"</td>");
                     out.println("<td>"+ end+"</td>");
                     out.println("<td>"+ date+"</td>");
                     out.println("</tr>");
                     out.println("</center></table><br><br>");
             }//2
        else if (availID == 7) {
                    //Table consist of same attribute as above
                }//7
               if (availID == 10) {
                   //Table consist of same attribute as above
               }//10
               if (availID == 16) {
                     //Table consist of same attribute as above
               }//16
               else if (availID != 2 && availID != 7 && availID != 10 && availID == 16) {
                    //Table consist of same attribute as above
                  }//else 

 }// first try
```

This codes can only retrieve the last value of the array set. But I would like to access all data of an array set.. How can i solve this? OR do i have to nested loop every condition one by one?

Comment: As i was writing a answer I realized you have some issues with the code. Are you sure your code runs without an exception? You are not setting the `Object[] array` variable, but later accessing it.

Comment: @Underbalanced there is exception of course. To be honest, i trimmed lots of my codes so it will not be too long. People dont wanna read it :( Unless youre requesting for it, Ill post the long one

Comment: what does this availID represent and where do you set? I see that you initialize with 0 but not setting it.

Comment: My answer would only be partially helpful without the code, because I have to make assumtions.

Comment: @Vijay i set `availID` in the array but I did not show it.. but I mentioned in the comment if you noticed.. The value of `availID` is retrieved from DAO

Comment: Would you like to see the whole codes? haha @Underbalanced. A little bit messy since I am still trial and error..

Comment: I am writing a generic answer to get you on the right track.

Comment: Sure :) Thank you @Underbalanced

Comment: @user6308605 Added answer, this is just a simple frame work to give you an idea of how to organize your problem space as well as do some basic sorting, as well as answer your questions to printing/grouping. Some stuff you need to finish implementing, like the switch as well as the `StudenExam` class data parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Over all your setup might make it harder to work with. I have rewrote what you are trying as well as grouped everything by availId. I typed this all up in notepad so please excuse any {} issues.

[Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

[Comparing Ints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29)

```
public class StudentExam {

            String studentName = null;
            String projectTitle = null;
            String SVName = null;
            String EXName = null;
            int availID = 0;
            String day = null;
            Time start = null;
            Time end = null;
            Date date = null;

    public StudentExam(Object[] studentExamArray){
        this.studentName = studentExamArray[7];
        this.projectTitle = studentExamArray[]; //TODO Insert index
        this.SVName = studentExamArray[];  //TODO Insert index
        this.EXName = studentExamArray[]; //TODO Insert index
        this.availID = studentExamArray[]; //TODO Insert index
        this.day = studentExamArray[]; //TODO Insert index
        this.start = studentExamArray[]; //TODO Insert index
        this.end = studentExamArray[]; //TODO Insert index
        this.date = studentExamArray[3]; //TODO Insert index
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    List<Object[]> list;

    try{ 
        List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>)GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i],studentID[i]);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printstacktrace();
        // Do something ?
    }

    if(list == null || list.size() == 0){
        return; // Or throw exception
    }


    List<StudentExam> studentExams = new ArrayList(); // here you can change the list implimentation and use to make a sorted list using a comparator or we can sort it later
    for(Object[] studenExamArray : list){
        StudenExam studentExam = new StudentExam(studenExamArray);
        studentExams.add(studentExam);
    }


    // Now that you have parsed your data you can go ahead and sort it, and print it the way you want...
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
                @Override
                public int compare(StudentExam se1, StudentExam se2) {
                    return Integer.compare(se1.availID, se2.availID)
                }  
            });


    for(StudentExam studenExam : studentExams){
        switch(studentExam.availID){
            case 0:{
                // Do stuff
                break;
            }
            case 0:{
                // Do stuff
                break;
            }
            case 0:{
                // Do stuff
                break;
            }
            case 0:{
                // Do stuff
                break;
            }
            case 0:{
                // Do stuff
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand it tbh

Comment: Basically I was taking and creating a class `StudentExam` to be able to help clear out the main method. This is where you build the data structure, then you simply sort them. Your code was missing a lot so i had to put //TODOs. The example i posted is very basic, not sure how else to help.

Comment: Is there any other way i can do without using `Collections.sort`?

Comment: @user6308605 You can change where the ArrayList and use a Sorted Data structure or you can replace the `Collections.sort();` with a manual sort using the temporary arrays. [Manually Sorting an Array in Ascending Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927714/manually-sorting-an-array-in-ascending-order).